# swift 3 alphanumeric sorting re: I, II, III, IV, IX, V,

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

Curious to know if anyone can offer a solution to sorting roman numerals (string type) I through X.  When I sort an array using {$0.compare ($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending}, I get I, II, III, IV, IX, V, VI, VII, VIII X.  As you can see, IX follows IV because of the "I."

By the way, the data model is a dictionary [**String**:[String:[String]]]  The Bold indicates where in the dictionary the data to be sorted exists.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean? Perhaps by converting them first

```
let romanValues = ["M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"]
let arabicValues = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1]

var romanValue = ""
var startingValue = number

for (index, romanChar) in enumerate(romanValues) {
    var arabicValue = arabicValues[index]

    var div = startingValue / arabicValue

    if (div > 0)
    {
        for j in 0..<div
        {
            //println("Should add \(romanChar) to string")
            romanValue += romanChar
        }

        startingValue -= arabicValue * div
    }
}

return romanValue
```

Comment: Clever idea.  However, the key reads:  Article I, Article II, Article III and so on.

Comment: @P.Festus So parse it out first

Comment: By parse, you mean separate out the first part of the string: "Article" ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple solution. Rather than hassle with the key of the dictionary to populate the rows of a table view in the desired numeric order, I created a simple array- which is ordered.  When a row is selected, I can use didSelectRow to identify the indexPath and the related string of the array- for example row 1 = "Article I".  I can then pass the selected string value "Article I" as a variable to use in the selection of the identical key [**String**:[String:[String]]] within the nested dictionary.

PS - the solution posted by Lucas appears to be a partial copy and paste of a function that can be found on GitHub. It appears Lucas inadvertently failed to copy and paste the entire function.